# Error at startup on Linux after computer shutdown during Ubuntu 18 update

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, updates, reboot, data-corruption

I tried to update my laptop to Ubuntu 18.04 (from 16.04) last night, but I had a power outage and I believe it was interrupted in the middle. As I woke up and noticed that the power was out, I panicked, and, yeah, system corrupted as the laptop ran out of power.

Can anyone give some instructions on how to repair the system?

[Picture of the error message showing at startup](https://image.ibb.co/f0CdW9/20181007_235357.jpg)

Full StartupError Message:

```
[     1.271631 ] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[     1.271695 ] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu
[     1.271753 ] Hardware name: ASUSTEeK Computer Inc. G74Sx/G74Sx, BIOS G74Sx.202 08/15/2011
[     1.271820 ] Call Trace: 
[     1.271873 ]    dump_stack+0x63/0x8b
[     1.271924 ]    panic+0xe4/0x244
[     1.271974 ]    mount_block_root+0x1f6/0x2da
[     1.272025 ]    ? set_debug_rodata+0x17/0x17
[     1.272075 ]    mount_root+0x38/0x3a
[     1.272126 ]    prepare_namespace+0x139/0x18e
[     1.272186 ]    kernel_init_freeable+0x224/0x251
[     1.272189 ]    ? rest_init+0xb0/0xb0
[     1.272191 ]    kernel_init+0xe/0x110
[     1.272193 ]    ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[     1.272243 ] Kernel Offset: 0x24400000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[     1.272505 ] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

On startup, choose Advanced options for Ubuntu in the GNU GRUB menu, then enter in recovery mode, such as `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-137-generic (recovery mode)`.
Once it loads, run `fsck`, reboot after finished, then get in recovery mode again and run `dpkg`. I had to run each of these a few times, as it kept getting stuck at different points, and I had to cancel it some times...
Once done with these, get in recovery mode and on root, and run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install -f
grub-update
grub-update2
reboot
```

Enter on recovery mode once more, and just resume. It worked for me, and I was inside the interface, where I opened a terminal and reran all of the commands above, as well as completed installation through interface windows that showed up as the system started.

Comment: I got the same error when trying to boot in recovery mode...