# Kernel panic trying to boot 4.4.0-146-generic after apt upgrade on 16.04.6

Tags: 16.04, kernel

I can't boot the 4.4.0-146-generic kernel because of a kernel panic. I'm running 16.04.6 on an Intel Core i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4. See image below:

[image: Kernel panic booting 4.4.0.146]

Comment: You can try booting the previous kernel version on Grub's Advanced Options submenu. Let us know if that works ok.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, yes that worked fine and [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0) already solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot your Linux from the live CD/DVD, into the recovery mode prompt, then check your root fs, e.g.

```
fsck /dev/your_drive
```

<sup>Note: Add `-y` to fix any errors automatically.</sup>

Or:

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage
fsck -y /dev/mapper/dom0_root
```

Source: [Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/qubes-users/e56-LZbKrZU).

Answer (score 0):

The usual cause can be:

- Broken grub config.
- Root partition not flagged as bootable.
- Bad installation (`initramfs` lacks or uses modules of another kernel version).
- Bad RAM, try replacing. See: [Random Kernel Panic on boot - not syncing](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=262342).

You can try to fix your Grub record by:

1. Mount your LXLE `/boot` partition (for instance at `/mnt/boot`).
2. Install Grub bootloader by: `grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX`
3. Then run: `grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
4. Optionally, if it fails to detect your other system, edit `grub.cfg` file manually.

Source: [Kernel Panic on first boot](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=220288).

---

See also:

- [Error at startup on Linux after computer shutdown during Ubuntu 18 update](https://askubuntu.com/q/1081850/78223)